# ¿Por que el UL no ocupa todo el alto?

Tags: css, reactjs

Estoy intentando poner un `<ul>` que ocupe todo el alto de la pantalla. Lo igualé a `window.screen.height`, por lo que debería de ocupar el alto de mi pantalla, pero en cambio ocupa un alto mucho mayor. ¿Por que sucede esto y como puedo solucionarlo?

Componente:

```
export default class Menu extends Component {
    css =
    {
        height:window.screen.height,
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.props.class + " menuHamburger"}>
                <ul style={this.css}>
                    <li>link 1</li>
                    <li>link 2</li>
                    <li>link 3</li>
                    <li>link 4</li>
                    <li>link 5</li> 
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, el resultado debería verse hasta el link 5, en cambio el link4 y 5 quedan por fuera de la pantalla.

También adjunto otras propiedades css que afectan al `<ul>`:

```
.menuHamburger{
        position:fixed;
        z-index: -100;
        transition:transform 0.5s;
        background-color: blanchedalmond;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding:4vh;
    }
    .menuHamburger ul{
        list-style: none;
        padding:3vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    
    .menuHamburger li{
        padding:1vh
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta usar:

```
.menuHamburger {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

100vh corresponde al alto total del viewport.

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias